# Shared Server: Python Script run under UNIX Shell vs HTTP

Tags: python, shell, dreamhost, pycrypto

I have a Python script on my Dreamhost shared server. When I access my script via SSH (using the UNIX Shell) my script executes fine and is able to import the Pycrypto module `Crypto.Cipher`.

But if I access my script via HTTP using my websites url. The script fails when it goes to import the Pycrypto module `Crypto.Cipher`. It gives the error `ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher`.

Do you know what might be causing this weird error? And how I can fix it.

Some important information:
 - I have installed a custom version of python on my shared server. Its just Python 2.7 with Pycrypto and easy_install installed.
- I am certain that the script is running under Python 2.7 and not Dreamhosts default 2.6 version. I know this because the script prints `sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` both in the UNIX shell and HTTP.
- I installed Pycrypto manually (using tar, and running setup.py) as opposed to using easy_install or pip.
- I have editted my .bash_profile's PATH variable correctly (well I believe I have done it correctly because the script is run under Python 2.7 not 2.6).

Any advice would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server does not read your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: doesn't read it when the script is run under SSH (UNIX Shell), under HTTP or both?

Comment: When you SSH into the server, you run an interactive shell. The shell reads its startup files. The web server which serves your HTTP requests does not do this.